# install downloaded apk programmatically

Tags: java, android, apk

I searched to stack and find the below method to install apk but it doesn't work correctly on android API 6 and higher.when this method become run this error on mobile screen appeared

> "There is a Problem Parsing the Package"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(PathManagers.getApk(context) + zipFileNameUnzipApk));
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

if (intent.resolveActivityInfo(context.getPackageManager(), 0) != null)
{
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
else
{

    // if you reach this place, it means there is no any file
    // explorer app installed on your device
}
```

Comment: what are the issues are you having?

Comment: Please edit your question and explain in detail what "doesn't work correctly" means. Note that you cannot use `Uri.fromFile()` here on Android 7.0+ devices (you will need to switch to using `FileProvider` to serve the file). Also, you are better served using `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` rather than `ACTION_VIEW`.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted then use this method

```
     private void installApk(String filename) {
    File file = new File(filename);
    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            //final String command = " pm install -r " + file.getAbsolutePath();
            final String command = "pm install -r " + file.getAbsolutePath();

            //Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command });
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ProjectUtils.PSLogger(TAG, "error while installation of apk");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I never used the rooted devices phrase in my question,but thanks because of your answer